# Unable to resolve ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm:dh key too small issue in nodejs https request

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, httprequest, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to invoke a webservice using https request in my node.js code. But Im getting **SSL routines:ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm:dh key too small:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c** error.

Even tried downloading the full certificate chain from the host website and added the certificate to the https request while invoking the URL but still got the same error.

### Here is the https request code that I'm using to invoke the service.

```
var https = require("https");

let fs = require('fs');

exports.connect = function (param, callback) {
  try {
  const options = {
      protocol: 'https',
      host: 'hostname',
      path: 'fullpath',
      method: 'GET',
      cert = fs.readFileSync(cert.cer)
    };
    let jsonObj = "";
    var req = https.request(options, function (res, error) {
      var chunks = [];
      console.log(res);
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });
      res.on("end", function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        try {
          jsonObj=body.toString();
          console.log("Response is " + jsonObj);
          return(null, jsonObj);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return callback(error, null)
        }
      });
    });
    req.end();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return callback(err, null)
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";` does not work for me for this error.